# I have question when creating blog with github

Tags: github, blogs

When I run
hexo d
in Git Bash
It jumped out :

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/rippleQAQ/rippleQAQ.github.io.git/' not found
FATAL {
  err: Error: Spawn failed
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HCC\Desktop\blog\myblog\node_modules\hexo-util\lib\spawn.js:51:21)
      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at cp.emit (C:\Users\HCC\Desktop\blog\myblog\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
      at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
    code: 128
  }
} Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: %s https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
```

rippleQAQ is my github name,and I've created a repository named rippleQAQ.github.io and SSH key

my _config.yml is:

```
# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/one-command-deployment
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/rippleQAQ/rippleQAQ.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

I need some help.Thank you.

I tried delete and recreate my github repository again and again.And change _config.yml.But it was no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Hexo: GitHub Pages](https://hexo.io/docs/github-pages), if you go the Project page route (as opposed to GitHub Action), you would need to:

1. Navigate to your repo on GitHub. Go to the Settings tab. Change the Repository name so your blog is available at `username.github.io/repository`, repository can be any name, like blog or hexo.
2. Edit your `_config.yml`, change the url: value to `https://username.github.io/repository`.
3. Commit and push to the default branch.
4. Once the deployment is finished, the generated pages can be found in the `gh-pages` branch of your repository.
5. In your GitHub repo’s setting, navigate to `Settings > Pages > Source`. Change the branch to `gh-pages` and save.
6. Check the webpage at `username.github.io/repository`.

Meaning: you need to manually add, commit and push your code, to the main branch (*not* `master`, [since oct. 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories-is-now-main/))

And your `_config.yml` should use the `gh-pages` branch.

```yaml
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/<username>/<project>
  # example, https://github.com/hexojs/hexojs.github.io
  branch: gh-pages
```

Comment: In _config.yml
I changed
repo: https://github.com/rippleQAQ/rippleQAQ.github.io.git
to
repo: https://github.com/rippleQAQ/rippleQAQ.github.io
and ran
hexo clean
hexo g
hexo d
Then I finally finish it.
It's my first blog!!!
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @rippleQAQ Great, well done!